# Android Fragment create duplicate tabs every time when I come back to same fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have create the sample activity using frame layout and fragment with tabs. However, when I switch to other activity/fragment and than comes back to same activity/fragment, it always create duplicate entry or view for tabs. for example, I have tab1 and tab2, when I view activity for first time it display two tabs, but when i switch to other activity and comes back to tabs activity it display four tabs, 'tab1, tab2, tab1, tab2'.

This is my code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater Inflater, ViewGroup Container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if(savedInstanceState==null) {
        rootView = Inflater.inflate(R.layout.loanapplicationview, Container, false);

        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();

        // Hide Actionbar Icon
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        // Hide Actionbar Title
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        // Create Actionbar Tabs
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Set Tab Icon and Titles
        Tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1");
        Tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2");


        // Set Tab Listeners
        Tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab1));
        Tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab2));


        // Add tabs to actionbar
        actionBar.addTab(Tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(Tab2);

    }
    return rootView;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the tabs exist before adding them.

```
if (actionBar.getTabCount() == 0) {
    // Set Tab Icon and Titles
    Tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab1");
    Tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Tab2");

    // Set Tab Listeners
    Tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab1));
    Tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(fragmentTab2));

    actionBar.addTab(Tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(Tab2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ActionBar().removeAllTabs()` will remove all the tabs attached to your `ActionBar`.
So before addinf new tabs clear the previous ones with this method

```
   actionBar.removeAllTabs();

// Add tabs to actionbar
    actionBar.addTab(Tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(Tab2);
```

Comment: thanks for your inputs and your solution work absolutely for my code. However, I do not want to reload the data in tab when it was initially loaded. Is there any way we can display same data?

Comment: please mark it as valid answer if it solves your issue

Comment: but my issue regarding " I do not want to reload the data in tab when it was initially loaded. Is there any way we can display same data?" solved by @Dreagen completely.....